# jQuery Ajax Race Condition best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In a `button.click(function(){});` I have the following code:

```
var userId = $("#user-permission-edit").val();
        var peId = $("#user-permission-entity-list").val();
        var newParentPEId = $("#new-parent-pe").val();
        var newPeName = $("#pe-name-add").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'AddNewPE',
            data: { 'targetUserId': userId, 'targetPEId': peId, 'newPeParentId': newParentPEId, 'newPeName': newPeName},
            success: function (data) {
                var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(dataObj);

                if (dataObj.status == "success") {
                    alert("Permissions have been updated.");
                }
                //update user PEs combo

            }
        });
```

However, I am concerned of a possible race condition of the variables not getting the values in time for the ajax call.

would something like this be safer?

```
  var userId = $("#user-permission-edit").val();
    var peId = $("#user-permission-entity-list").val();
    var newParentPEId = $("#new-parent-pe").val();
    var newPeName = $("#pe-name-add").val();


    $.when(function() {
         userId = $("#user-permission-edit").val();
         peId = $("#user-permission-entity-list").val();
         newParentPEId = $("#new-parent-pe").val();
         newPeName = $("#pe-name-add").val();

    }).done(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'AddNewPE',
            data: { 'targetUserId': userId, 'targetPEId': peId, 'newPeParentId': newParentPEId, 'newPeName': newPeName},
            success: function (data) {
                var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(dataObj);

                if (dataObj.status == "success") {
                    alert("Permissions have been updated.");
                }
                //update user PEs combo

            }
        });

    });
```

Is this even necessary?

Comment: Are those elements created by some other part of your code? As long as they're present in the DOM, there's no worry of the values not being set. The ajax call won't be made until after the code before it finishes.

Comment: that isn't necessary. I haven't come across any errors like that with what youre trying to do because its a synchronous call.... jQuery recommends using button.on('click', function() { }); just as a fyi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$('....').val()` method is a synchronous call - your script execution won't continue past that line until you have received the value of that element.